# ColdFusion Exporting to Excel

Tags: coldfusion

I have a Excel filte that was exported from ColdFusion data. My question is do we have an option to move U & V column cells to the left of column B using ColdFusion. Here my code below :

```
   <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=Reporting.xls"> 
    <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
    <table cellspacing="1" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="border-style:none;">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="cellSpacer">&nbsp;</th>
                <th colspan="7" class="colorHeader">Major Maintenance Expenditure ($k)</th>
                <th class="cellSpacer">&nbsp;</th>
                <th colspan="7" class="colorHeader">Capital Expenditure ($k)</th>
                <th class="cellSpacer">&nbsp;</th>
                <th colspan="7" class="colorHeader">Asset Retirement Obligations ($k)</th>
                <th class="cellSpacer">&nbsp;</th>
                <th colspan="7" class="colorHeader">Environmental Liability ($k)</th>
                <th class="cellSpacer">&nbsp;</th>

            </tr>
<cfoutput query="Myqry">
           <tr>
               <td>#Myquery.columns1#</td>
           </tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you not have control of the query that's giving you the xls file? It would be easier to handle as early as possible.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If it's your code, why not just swap the column positions in your cfoutput?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple one-linear to solve the problem entirely, Just use the `cfspreadsheet` tag.

```html
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="C:\sheet.xlsx" query="query" >
```

And... You are done. You can read more about this tag from [here.](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend looking into <cfspreadsheet> https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html